# Help with an interactive Emacs Lisp function for replacing text

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've been using Emacs for a couple months now, and I want to get started in elisp programming. Specifically, I'd like to write my own `interactive` function. However, I'm more than a bit lost. `(interactive ...)` has tons of options and I'm not sure which one I want. Then, I don't really know the names of the functions I need. If someone could kindly help me turn my pseudocode into real code, I would be mighty appreciative! (And as always, any links to informative places would be good. Right now I've just been reading [this.](http://www.rattlesnake.com/intro/index.html))

Here is pseudocode for what I'd like to do:

```
(defun my-func (buffer) ; I think I need the buffer as an arg?
  "does some replacements"
  (interactive ???) ; ?
  (let (replacements (list
   '("a-regexp-string" . "a-replacement-string-with-backreferences")
   ...)) ; more of the above
    (while replacements
      (let (current (car replacements)) ; get a regexp-replacement pair
        (some-regexp-replace-func buffer (car current) (cdr current)) ; do the replacement
        (setq replacements (cdr replacements))))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, from the looks of your function you would probably be doing it in the current buffer, so no, you don't need to have a 'buffer' argument.  If that's a bad assumption, I can change the code.  Next, in a 'let' if you are assigning to variables you need another set of parens around each pair of var/value.  Finally, when looping through a list I prefer to use functional-programming-like functions (mapcar, mapc, etc.).  I'll try to inline some comments here:

```
(defun my-func ()
  "Do some replacements"
  (interactive)
  (let ((replacements (list '("foo" . "bar")
                            '("baz" . "quux"))))
    (save-excursion ; So point isn't moved after this function
      (mapc (lambda (x) ; Go through the list, with this 'inline' function
                        ; being called with each element as the variable 'x'
              (goto-char (point-min)) ; Start at the beginning of the buffer
              (while (re-search-forward (car x) nil t) ; Search for the car of the replacement
                (replace-match (cdr x)))) ; And replace it with the cdr
            replacements)))) ; The list we're mapc'ing through
```

As for what to read, I'd suggest the Elisp manual that comes with Emacs.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me understand what was going on and get on the right track. I just had to use `re-search-forward` instead of the non-regexp version, and not pass `t` to `replace-match` so that referencing of matched groups works. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I was just coming back to fix those :)